# Using a sub domain on my local machine without specifying the port

Tags: xampp

I have a domain that I purchased from my web host. I want to use the subdomain that I have created on my local machine as the files that I am using cannot be installed on the host.

As of right now the subdomain works, however I have to include the port at the end in order to view the site/files that I want. I am hosting statping in case my host were to go down the status page is still up. I am hosting statping on a Windows 10 machine, statping has its own HTTP server. I am using XAMPP.

Answer (score 1):

You can omitt the port if you are using standard-ports.

So you have to set the port to 80 for http or to 443 for https.

When using https you also need a ssl-certificate to encrypt traffic.

Comment: I cant use port 80 as XAMPP is already using it. Im also needing to run two instances of statping for two different sites.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, what you are trying to do, is to use your own computer as hosting for two instances of statping in subdomains.

I can assume you have all the network part solved, (ip address changes, ports open in your router, etc.) since you comment that you can access the page from outside your network adding the port in the URL.

Scenario 1- Statping uses is own http server, in this case you can change the ports xampp is using to clear them, so statping can use the standard ports, i have my local environment in port :8888, this is taking in consideration you are not using xampp to serve other websites that need standard ports. Im not familiar with statping or the web server it uses, but i highly doubt you can run 2 instances in the same port.

Scenario 2 - Serve the statping instances using xampp, to do this you can configure apache virtual hosts, you have one instance of the web server with will identify the header to know wich status page should serve.

this guide can help

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/configure-virtual-host-on-windows-10-for-wordpress/

Comment: Basically i do not want to have to enter the port along with the domain to access the site, I just want to enter the domain only.

Comment: ok, ¿but are you using the statping own http server? ¿or xampp?

Comment: I have to use statpings http server, i have no other choice, its built in.

Comment: Then you dont have another choice but change the port in xampp to clear the 80 port for statping